# Is it still called linear separation with a layer of more than 1 neuron

Tags: deep-learning, math, deep-neural-networks, artificial-neuron, linear-regression

A single neuron will be able to do linear separation. For example, XOR simulator network:

```
x1 --- n1.1
   \  /    \
    \/      \
             n2.1 
    /\      /
   /  \    /
x2 --- n1.2
```

Where `x1`, `x2` are the 2 inputs, `n1.1` and `n1.2` are the 2 neurons in hidden layer, and `n2.1` is the output neuron.

The output neuron `n2.1` does a **linear separation**. How about the 2 neurons in hidden layer?

**Is it still called linear separation** (at 2 nodes and join the 2 separation lines)? or **polynomial separation of degree 2**?

I'm confused about how it's called because there are curvy lines in this wiki article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overfitting

[image: Some curvy separation?]

[image: Some other curvy separation?]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the curvy zigzag green line is not polynomial as if it were polynomial, a vertical line won't cut that curvy line more than 1 time.

It's the combination of straight lines (linear separation) of multiple neurons in the same layer. So it's linear separation ('linear' by previous_layer_output*weight, 'separation' by activation function), at multiple nodes.

Answer (score 0):

What you have depicted is a nonlinear classificator. Although each stage does a linear separation, the sequential composition of linear separations is nonlinear. The nonlinearity of the neuron is key in this regard, as otherwise it would all be equivalent to a matrix multiplication, which is linear. You were right about the degree, although it's rarely called like that. People usually describe just the number of layers, and I guess the main reason is that it's not directly equivalent to such polynomials, as that depends on other factors (e.g. the activation function).